# Best Practice: Using jquery .load() with PHP to both pass data from Javascript and retrieve from PHP. How to pass data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Lots of info/questions on Ajax/.load() and a little overwhelmed. Looking to take the most efficient approach.

**Goal:** Execute ajax request onclick; pass the innerHTML of clicked item to PHP for use in MySQL DB query. Write query result to particular element.

**Progress:**

Not sure whether to use .load() or .ajax().

.load() option allows a 'plain object or string' to be sent to the server with the request and easy to specify where to write the data using selector. Jquery documentation: .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] ).

Trying to implement this method first.

```
 $(".classExample").click(function(){
 innerHTMLtoBeUsedInPHP = this.innerHTML;
 $("#writeDataHere").load("dateAjax.php",innerHTMLtoBeUsedInPHP);
 });


<?php echo 'Passing data from PHP back to client-side is sorted with the echo'.$_GET['innerHTMLtoBeUsedInPHP']; ?>
```

According to the jquery documentation, the POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed. The innerHTML is a string so GET used.

Why can I not access the 'innerHTMLtoBeUsedInPHP' in my PHP script?

Comment: What you are sending to the server is by GET, so your url will look like `dateAjax.php?<li>asdf</li>...more html`. Probably not ideal. You could still access the data using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in php but there would be a limit on how much data you could send which is likely smaller than you need. I would suggest changing the innerHTML in the load call to something like `{"data":innerHTMLtoBeUsedInPHP}` which would change the call to a post and make the data available as `$_POST['data']` in php.

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated. This answers my question if you wanna put as answer and I can close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are sending to the server is by `GET`, so your url will look like `dateAjax.php?<li>asdf</li>...more html`. Probably not ideal. You could still access the data using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in php but there would be a limit on how much data you could send which is likely smaller than you need. I would suggest changing the innerHTML in the load call to something like `{"data":innerHTMLtoBeUsedInPHP}` which would change the call to a post and make the data available as `$_POST['data']`